# How to pass id from view to Action on a controller

Tags: c#, html, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to devise a way to add and remove posts from a web log. So far I have the following code in my view.

```
@foreach (Comment comment in comments.OrderBy(x => x.CommentCreateDate))
{

    <div>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => comment.CommentId)<br/>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => comment.CommentCreateDate)<br />
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => comment.CommentUpdateDate)<br />
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => comment.CommeterName)<br/>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => comment.EmailAddress)<br/>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => comment.CommentText)<br />
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => comment.Approved)
</div>
    <hr />


}

@*@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = post.PostId }) |*@


<form method="get" action="ApproveComment">
    <input type="submit" id="btnApproveComment" class="btn-default" value="Approve" />
    <input type="submit" id="btnDelete" class="btn-default" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

Then in my Action I have as follows:

```
//[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ApproveComment(int id)
        {

            bool isChecked = false;
            Comment comment = new Comment();

            if (Request.Form["chkApprove"] != null)
            {
                isChecked = Convert.ToBoolean((Request.Form["chkApprove"]));
            }

            comment.CommentId = id;
            comment.Approved = isChecked;
            db.Comments.Add(comment);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return View("Admin");
        }
```

My Comment Model:

```
public class Comment
    {

        // Comments have id, poast, id, time, email, comment,
        [Key]
        public int CommentId { get; set; }
        public int PostId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PostId")]
        public virtual Post Post{get; set;}
        public string CommentCreateDate { get; set; }
        public string CommentUpdateDate { get; set; }
        public string CommeterName { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string CommentText { get; set; }
        public bool Approved { get; set; }
    }
```

My Post model:

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate{get;set;}
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set;}
    /// <summary>
    /// tag has posts and posts have tag -
    /// </summary>
    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

}
```

What I want really is be able to choose the comments with the Check box and then either delete or approve a comment. For this I need to pass the ID and while I see that I can do that with Action Link I don’t want a link, just to pass the ID and the value of the check box.

Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not a million miles away, if you place your current code *inside* a form and then have it post it should post the value of the check box results because `CheckBoxFor` is an *editable* field.

Using `CheckBoxFor` is key (or any other editor extension) because the UI is rendered specifically with posting back to the server in mind therefore it decorates the markup with special attributes which the MVC model binder uses to map your form to your C# model

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Comments", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @foreach (Comment comment in comments.OrderBy(x => x.CommentCreateDate))
    {
        <div>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => comment.CommentId)<br/>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => comment.CommentCreateDate)<br />
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => comment.CommentUpdateDate)<br />
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => comment.CommeterName)<br/>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => comment.EmailAddress)<br/>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => comment.CommentText)<br />
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => comment.Checked)
        </div>
    }  
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="btnApproveComment" name="action" class="btn-default" value="Approve" />
    <input type="submit" id="btnDelete" name="action" class="btn-default" value="Delete" />
}
```

Then at the server side you just need to determine what action the user invoked i.e. approve or delete. To do this, you can set the name of each button in your form to be the same value and determine the action based on the value posted i.e.

```
public ActionResult Save(MyModel model, string action)
{
    var commentsToAction = model.Comments.Where(x => x.Checked);
    if (action == "Approve") {
        foreach (var c in commentsToAction) {
            // approve c
        }
    } else if (action == "Delete") {
        foreach (var c in commentsToAction) {
            // delete c
        }
    }
}
```

Note - assuming you are using a view model, you could also just add your `Action` property to `MyModel` and then you wouldn't need to manually look into the `FormCollection`, you would just check `model.Action`.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers! I have tested your solution and I am getting an exception which I think happens because the comments are in a post. I have added the models for clarity but I think the parameter of the action should be post for it to work....

Comment: @bluetxxth could you post the exception? Bare in mind I have assumed you have a property called "Checked" in your model which is used server side to determine which comments are checked in the view

Comment: I would skip the Request.Form part and just add the parameter `string action` and the value of that will be the value of the button clicked

Comment: @James Exception is  Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source

Comment: @bluetxxth where does the exception happen? That looks like a LINQ one so would probably be related to the `model.Comments.Where(x => ...)` line if you are using the code above. `MyModel` would be `Post` in your scenario check that the action is being hit and the `Comments` list is assigned.

Comment: @James the exception happens just as you indicated at the LINQ. Comments list is assigned and the actions are hit. The problem is really that Post is null when it comes as a parameter into the action Save(). I am not sure how to pass it from the view, to the controller at the same time as I am passing Comment.

Comment: @bluetxxth it should be `Post` that you are sending from the view, not an individual comment. The `Post` model has a list of comments and that's what you are "updating".

Answer (score 0):

I have just found out that I have to do something like this to pass the id:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("ApproveComment", new { id = comment.CommentId });}
```

Answer (score -1):

@Html.ActionLink creates an anchor tag (<a>) which is not the right element for the job.

Your proposed solution won't work as both submit inputs will trigger the same form action.

```
<form method="get" action="ApproveComment">
    <input type="submit" id="btnApproveComment" class="btn-default" value="Approve" />
    <input type="submit" id="btnDelete" class="btn-default" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

A <button type="submit">Approve<button>> or <input type="submit" value="Approve" /> triggers the action on its closest parent <form>.

Doing this *without* AJAX; you'll need to create two forms.

You should use the HtmlHelper to create the form so that the proper route values are passed to its action, e.g. (where "ApproveComment"/"DeleteComment" is the action, "Post" is the name used for PostController)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ApproveComment", "Post", FormMethod.Post, new { id = post.PostId })) {
    <button type="submit">Approve</button>
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteComment", "Post", FormMethod.Post, new { id = post.PostId })) {
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
}
```

Hope that helps.